# Why isn't my ValueConverter being triggered?

Tags: wpf, f#

**Why isn't my ValueConverter being triggered?**

My value-converter is triggered when the constructor of my view-model is executed. However, it doesn't get triggered when I assign a new value to the Cells property.

**I expect this line to trigger my value-converter update:**

```
this.Cells <- grid |> cycleThroughCells
                   |> Map.toSeq
                   |> Seq.map snd
                   |> Seq.toList
```

But it doesn't.

**I have the following ViewModel:**

```
type ViewModel() as this =
    inherit ViewModelBase()

    let rowCount = 6
    let mutable grid = rowCount |> createGrid
                                |> setCell { X=3; Y=1; State=Alive }
                                |> setCell { X=3; Y=0; State=Alive }
                                |> setCell { X=4; Y=1; State=Alive }

    let mutable _cells = grid |> Map.toSeq
                              |> Seq.map snd
                              |> Seq.toList
    let cycleHandler _ = 

        this.Cells <- grid |> cycleThroughCells
                           |> Map.toSeq
                           |> Seq.map snd
                           |> Seq.toList
    member this.Play =
        DelegateCommand ((fun _ -> let timer = createTimer 500 cycleHandler
                                   do while true do
                                      do Async.RunSynchronously timer), fun _ -> true) :> ICommand
    member this.Cells
        with get() = _cells 
        and set(value) =
            _cells <- value
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.Cells @>)
```

**My ViewModelBase is the following:**

```
open System.ComponentModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

type ViewModelBase () =
    let propertyChanged = 
        Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()

    let getPropertyName = function 
        | PropertyGet(_,pi,_) -> pi.Name
        | _ -> invalidOp "Expecting property getter expression"

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    member private this.NotifyPropertyChanged propertyName = 
        propertyChanged.Trigger(this,PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))

    member this.NotifyPropertyChanged quotation = 
        quotation |> getPropertyName |> this.NotifyPropertyChanged
```

**My XAML is the following:**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client;assembly=Client"
        Background="Black"
        Title="Game of Life" Height="450" Width="500">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StateToBrushConverter x:Key="StateToBrushConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />

            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />

            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />

            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Cells[0], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding Cells[1], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{Binding Cells[2], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{Binding Cells[3], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Fill="{Binding Cells[4], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Fill="{Binding Cells[5], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Cells[6], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding Cells[7], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{Binding Cells[8], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{Binding Cells[9], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Fill="{Binding Cells[10], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Fill="{Binding Cells[11], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Cells[12], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding Cells[13], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{Binding Cells[14], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{Binding Cells[15], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Fill="{Binding Cells[16], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Fill="{Binding Cells[17], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Cells[18], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding Cells[19], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{Binding Cells[20], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{Binding Cells[21], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Fill="{Binding Cells[22], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Fill="{Binding Cells[23], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Cells[24], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding Cells[25], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{Binding Cells[26], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{Binding Cells[27], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Fill="{Binding Cells[28], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Fill="{Binding Cells[29], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Cells[30], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{Binding Cells[31], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{Binding Cells[32], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{Binding Cells[33], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Fill="{Binding Cells[34], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5" Fill="{Binding Cells[35], Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}" />


        <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Content="Go!" Command="{Binding Play}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**My ValueConverter is the following:**

```
type StateToBrushConverter() =
    interface IValueConverter with
        member x.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture) = 
            let cell = value :?> Cell
            match cell.State with 
            | Alive -> SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen) :> obj
            | Dead  -> SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)      :> obj

        member x.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture) = failwith "Not implemented yet"
```

Comment: It is very, very bad code. What do you want to do?

Comment: But I strongly advise you to use [FSharp.ViewModule.Core](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.ViewModule.Core) - so you separate the flies from cutlets =)

Comment: @ Foggy Finder - I really want to understand core F# fundamentals. Thus, I don't want to depend on frameworks. I realize that my XAML is bad. However, I'm not clear on how I can improve other parts of my code. Any constructive suggestions?

Comment: I remember this advice was given long ago. But I think you understand the principle of operation commands, so as to take advantage of the packages.

Comment: If you describe what you want to do, I'll write an example.

Comment: I mean not only the use of IValueConverter

Comment: @ Foggy Finder - I want to update my grid (i.e. XAML implementation) on a half-second cadence. Specifially, I want to change the colors of my cells based on the ValueConverter I provided that converts a state to a brush.

Comment: Read [Introduction to Functional Programming](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/Lectures/funprog-jrh-1996/all.pdf) by John Harrison which is about the ML programming language and can be converted in to F#, I assure you will learn the basics and it does not rely on frameworks and only has a small section that uses mutables and state which are only included to cover the programming language. Some things cannot be converted to F# but finding them will help in learning and understanding F#.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know very well English - perhaps there is a misunderstanding. I want to write an example, but not sure I understand, what you want to achieve in your code. The main mistake that you are using XAML incorrectly.

Comment: @ Guy Coder - Thanks. I did buy your recommendation, "An Introduction to Functional Programming through Lambda Calculus". However, it was beyond my reading comprehension.

Comment: @ Foggy Finder - I want to bind a list to a grid and change the color of a cell on the grid based on a property of an element within the list.

Comment: Most likely you just need to set the size for the rectangle: MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"

Comment: but...this is a bad approach. In WPF it is best to use a list (or something like that) with a modified template.

Comment: If you give me the code for `createGrid` and `setCell`, I can write an example.

Comment: Thx Foggy - Here's the repo: https://github.com/bizmonger/GameOfLife

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106816/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-scott-nimrod).

Comment: @ScottNimrod This is a different book, did you take a look at it? It is closer to F# and explains how to go from lambda calculus to ML which uses let statements. If then a book about OCAML such as [Think OCaml -
How to Think Like a (Functional) Programmer](http://greenteapress.com/thinkocaml/thinkocaml.pdf) you should be able to see how the F# language evolved and better understand how functional programs are more like math than recipes.

Comment: @ScottNimrod If you put a space between the @ and the OP name, the OP will not be notified. I did not get any notifications because of the space. I only saw the comment by checking this question.

Comment: @ Guy Coder - Thank you for that suggestion. I made the update. However, my value converter is still not being called after I raise the propertychange event.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Please stop putting a space between the @ and the OP tag. We do not get the notifications of the comment when you insert a space.

Comment: @ScottNimrod have you any binding expression errors in your output window?

Comment: No errors in my output window.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Binding into collections is typically odd - I'd make sure that you're setter is being called on the main (UI) thread, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yea, I have reason to believe that it wasn't executing on the UI thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I try to run this code I got the exception.
Not sure, this may be due, but this code works for me without errors:

```
 type MainViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()   
     
    let rowCount = 6
    let mutable grid = rowCount |> createGrid
                                |> setCell { Y=2; X=1; State=Alive }
                                |> setCell { Y=2; X=2; State=Alive }
                                |> setCell { Y=3; X=2; State=Alive }
                                |> setCell { Y=3; X=3; State=Alive }

    let mutable _cells = grid |> Map.toSeq
                              |> Seq.map snd
                              |> Seq.toList
    
    let mutable count = 0
    let mutable isEnabled = true

    let cycleHandler _ = 
        _cells <- grid |> cycleThroughCells
                       |> Map.toSeq
                       |> Seq.map snd
                       |> Seq.toList
        count <- count + 1
        self.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ self.Cells @>)
        self.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ self.Count @>)
       
    let change _ = 
        isEnabled <- false
        self.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ self.IsEnabled @>)
        
        async
            {
                while true do
                    do! Async.Sleep 2000
                    cycleHandler()
            }
        |> Async.Start

    member __.Play = DelegateCommand (change, fun _ -> isEnabled) :> ICommand
    member __.N = rowCount
    member __.Cells = _cells
    member __.Count = count
    member __.IsEnabled = isEnabled
```

I changed your Xaml, because I don't think to describe 36 rectangles is a good idea.
One option is to use a ListBox:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Go!" Command="{Binding Play}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"  Margin="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Count}"  Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}" IsEnabled="False"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding N}" Columns="{Binding N}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Stretch="Fill"
                               Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StateToBrushConverter}}"></Rectangle>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Thus you can create grid of different dimensions depending on the value of rowCount.

I added a variable "count" to show that the function is called with the specified interval, even though the picture does not change.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem lies in the fact that you're binding to individual elements of the list, but firing the NotifyPropertyChanged for the list itself.  Have you tried replacing the list with an ObservableCollection and using `Clear` + `AddRange` to repopulate it on each tick?

Comment: Thx. I tried using an ObservableCollection. However, it didn't resolve my issue.